# Connection String has too many " 's

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2017, connection-string

I am trying to create a query for inserting data:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=sPC;Initial Catalog=d;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
String st = "INSERT INTO data(blah , etc.);
```

But the connection string that is provided is throwing syntax errors because it has multiple `"` in it.

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PasswordSaverAutofill\PasswordSaverAutofill\testDatabase.mdf";Integrated Security=True
```

### It's a local saved file. I'm just using it for testing purposes. There has to be a way this will work right? or do people usually just not use local storage ever?

Attempting double quotes to "literal-out" out the local path.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to escape `"` for a string literal?

Comment: I didn't even know that was possible.

Comment: I thought there might be some trick out of using that exact syntax. Or a way to generate another connectionString.

Comment: You can use escape sequence. Escaping quotes in SQL is done by a double quote, so a '' or a "" will produce one escaped ' and ", respectively.

Comment: I just tried and it still doesn't like the syntax. Is saving the file locally, just something that nobody ever does?

Comment: sorry. I can't figure out how to post real pictures. Do you see in the link above, how it is all now finally registering as string but for some reason the local path is showing a syntax error?

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/string-literal

Answer (score 0):

I used sql server management studio to create a local database.